# Having troubles installing Ubuntu using Wubi

Tags: installation, windows-7, wubi

I am trying to install Ubuntu on My Toshiba laptop, it is a 64 bit system and is running windows 7 I keep on getting this error

Error executing command

```
command=C:\Users\A'den\AppData\Local\Temp\pylA524.tmp\bin]resize2fs.exe -C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk17744M
recal=1
stderr=
stdout=resie2fs 1.40.6 (09-Feb-2008)
Usage:
/cygdrive/c/Users/Aden/AppData/Local/Temp/pylA524.tmp/bin/resize
2fs.exe-f C:/disks/root.disk 17744M [-d debug_flags] [-f] [-F] [-p] device [new-size]
```

and the log file reads

Comment: Is that an apostrophe in your username or did you just type that out by hand? Can you post more of the log please (or pastebin it). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `Wubi` the way you install any other windows exe. Don't use any commands. When you restart Windows you will be asked which operating system to use - Windows 7 or Ubuntu.

I used this link - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Everything was so easy and worked.

Start over and follow all the instructions on the site. :)